# How to reschedule the pod from node in kubernetes ( baremetal servers )?

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes nodes are getting unscheduled while i initiate the drain or cordon but the pods which is available on the node are not getting moved to different node immediately ?

i mean, these pods are not created by daemonset.

So, how come, Application running pod can make 100% available when a node getting faulty or with some issues ?

any inputs ?

**command used :**

**To drain / cordon to make the node unavailable:**

```
kubectl drain node1
kubectl cordon node1
```

**To check the node status :**

```
kubectl get nodes
```

**To check the pod status before / after cordon or drain :**

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
kubectl describe pod <pod-name>
```

**Surprising part is , even node is unavailable, the pod status showing always running. :-)**

Comment: probably your pod was still in grace period because there's no --force option in your drain command.

Answer (score 0):

Pods by itself doesn't migrate to another node.

> You can use workload resources to create and manage multiple Pods for you. A controller for the resource handles replication and rollout and automatic healing in case of Pod failure. For example, if a Node fails, a controller notices that Pods on that Node have stopped working and creates a replacement Pod. The scheduler places the replacement Pod onto a healthy Node.

Some examples of controllers are:

- [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)
- [daemonset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/)
- [statefulsets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/)

Check this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/) to more information.